# How to add code for position sizing using stoploss

Tags: pine-script

I need help with three things

- quantity = I want the position size based on my stoploss so that my max loss is 25$,
- stoploss = i want my stoploss to be lowest low of previous two candlesticks
- takeprofit = I want the takeprofit to be 1.5 times of my stoploss, such that my R:R is 1:1.5

Below is the code i am having problem with

```
// Loss
bloss = ta.lowest(low, 2)
sloss = ta.highest(high, 2)

// Maximum risk per trade
risk_per_trade = 25

// Quantity calculation based on risk
bqt = strategy.equity * risk_per_trade / math.abs(close - bloss) / 100
sqt = strategy.equity * risk_per_trade / math.abs(sloss - close) / 100


//Declaring TP/SL variables

varip float longStopLoss = na
varip float longTakeProfit = na
varip float shortStopLoss = na
varip float shortTakeProfit = na


// Strategy
if (buySignal)
    strategy.entry("Buy", direction=strategy.long, qty=bqt)
    if strategy.position_size <= 0
        longStopLoss := bloss
        longTakeProfit := 1.5*(close-longStopLoss)+close


if (sellSignal)
    strategy.entry("Sell", direction=strategy.short, qty=sqt)
    if strategy.position_size <=0
        shortStopLoss := sloss
        shortTakeProfit := close - (1.5*(shortStopLoss-close))
```